# Need help with countability proof

Tags: proof-writing, cardinals

Show that a finite subset $A \subset B$, of a countable set is also countable.

I started by saying that by definition there exists an injection $f: A \rightarrow B$

not sure what to do now, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are your definitoins if *finite* doesn't imply countable right away?

Comment: assume it wasnt countable then would B be countable ?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean the set of finite subsets of $B$ is a countable family?

Answer (score 2):

As asked, because $B$ is countable you have an injection from $B \to \Bbb N$  As $A$ is a subset of $B$, the injection from $B$ restricted to $A$ is an injection into $\Bbb N$